# I have parent/child view controllers but UITableViewController is kinda jerky as Child VC.

Tags: ios, performance, ipad, uikit, uitableview

It's best to show by pictures here is what the app looks like, I created a custom tab parent controller to handle each tab:
[image]

Now this table view controller is as simple as you can get, I have 500 rows and I'm reusing cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"TESTING";


    return cell;
}
```

When I run this however, in the simulator (have not tested on device yet) the scrollview is annoyingly jerky when I scroll and **especially** as it slows down. When I just run the TableViewController as the main VC it's performance is much better, and I notice hardly any jerking. Is there something I need to adjust for the tablviewcontroller to perform better as a child view controller? is it my implementation of the Parent/Child VC's that's screwing it up?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I think we need to see how you implemented your parent/child VC's in order to help you.

Comment: Yea, you're probably right I was just hesitant to post tons of code. I actually figured out the issue though, I ended up running this on a device and it worked perfectly. I know I should have checked this first but I just assumed my MBP (i7 4GB Ram) would run it faster than the device but it must handle graphics differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tested it on a device and everything seems to work fine, I think the simulator is poor with graphics. I am going to do a few more tests and research to figure out why but I'm glad it's working.